# MYSQL - select id from A where (...) AND id from B=1

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL. I have 2 tables:

**TABLE A**

```
id | txt
 1 | abc
 2 | bcd
 3 | cde
```

**TABLE B**

```
id | accept
 1 | 1
 2 | 0
 3 | 1
```

I want to display `txt` (from table A) only if related record (the same `id`) `accept=1` (from table B).

I can do this by setting 2 MySQL queries, but I would like to make it by one MySQL query.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Do you mean you want to select only those records from Table A that have `accept=1` in Table B?

Comment: There is no relation between these tables. Could you explain?

Comment: Martynasma: Yes, exactly. So the result should be: 'abc' and 'cde'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

```
SELECT txt 
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.id=B.id
WHERE B.accept = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.txt
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.accept= 1
```

Comment: If `A.id = B.id` then you might as well forget the join and do `select txt from A where id = 1`. Ie. until the questioner defines the relation the question makes no sense.

Comment: Richard: 'id' is id_user. So i want to display only txt from users that where accepted (=1).

Comment: @AoW Your unedited question says something different. Maybe you want to edit your question to reflect your needs...